# How do you decide what kind of rhythm/time signature to use?

Tags: composition, rhythm, drums

What would make you want to use 4/4 time compared to 3/4 time? Or 6/8 time over 3/4 time? I'm starting to get a grip on understanding different rhythms and how to read them etc. but I want to understand why I should choose a certain time signature/rhythm when creating a song.

How do you approach building the rhythm when creating music?

Comment: Umm, how do you decide what size of shoes to buy? A size 40 foot will fit into a size 45 shoe, but it will probably not be comfortable while walking. A time signature depends on the length of repeated patterns. */4 versus */8 depends on the "least common denominator" of a pattern. If most of your notes are 8ths, it makes a lot more sense to say that there are N 8ths within a measure as opposed to N 4ths.

Comment: @Pyromonk - **lowest** common denominator makes more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on the mood you're going for, and honestly I'd say deciding a time signature, a key, a melody, and a concept are all things that are a part of your *decision* when composing a piece of *your own* and there shouldn't really *be* an answer.

That being said, here's my personal tip: start with trying to find a basic melody, or at least a subject / motif that you will repeat throughout your song. If you can feel the theme of your song usually a rhythm will come from that; rather than deciding and forcing your time signature and mechanically creating a melody from that, try creating your melody and basing your rhythm on that.

My advice personally is to start with 4/4. If you've never composed before or have very little experience with it, I find it to be easier because your measures are automatically divided into equal halves, which are then divided into equal halves on the beat. Triple time (like 3/4) carries the imbalance of the one strong beat to two matched weak beats and if you're more familiar with that style (waltzes are *always* triple time and you might have experience with that feel) then by all means start there.

If you find a melody you really like and really want to work with but it doesn't seem to work under either, don't be afraid to use compound time (5/4, 7/8) to fit your melody or even move between time signatures during the song. But as a start, I recommend using 4/4 (3/4 but only if you have especially more experience with triple time, for whatever reason that might be) and trying to envision a melody from that, and if that doesn't seem to work, try thinking of a chord progression for both 4/4 and 3/4 and going between them until you find a suitable melody you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the piece is a vocal, the stress pattern of the lyrics generally indicates the rhythm. There some options as to the number of unstressed syllables between stressed syllables. For example, dactyls can be represented by a long note and two short or an accented note and two unaccented or something similar.

A choice may be chosen based on tradition (makes sightreading easier.) Waltzes are almost always written in 3/4. Some classical pieces are in 3/8 (and one in 5/8); never in 6/8 (or 6/4 as these are compound meters). Foxtrots, tangos, rumbas, boleros, mambos, cha-cha-chas, quicksteps, etc. are generally written in 4/4. Some years ago, tangos (and rags) were written mostly in 2/4 but played as 4/8 with the eighth note as the pulse; one must be cognizant of performance practice. Marches are often written in 4/4 or 2/4 or 6/8 depending on whether a triplet feel is wanted (Washington Post vs Stars and Stripes Forever). Samba is often in 2/2 (cut time)

Older dances (not commonly danced nowadays) have their own conventions. Sarabande is in 3/2; gig is usually in 6/8; gavotte is in 4/4 but starting mid measure; polonaise is in 3/4 as are minuet and mazurka.

Some centuries ago, time signatures also carried tempo information. Some of that carries over; one tends to play 6/8 a bit faster than 6/4 if not other information is made.

Comment: I can name loads of clasical music in 6/8 time (e.g. most Chopin ballades), and Chopin's Ballade No. 1 in G Minor is even mostly in 6/4 time. If you meant "never in 6/8" to be for waltzes only, please make this more clear.

Comment: I meant that for waltzes. Thanks. There is a slight problem in that dance patterns move in pairs of 3/4 measures. Most of the music pairs up the measures too. It's not so easy to describe, 6/4 describes triplets with a 2-beat feel and doesn't really sound like a single two 3/4 group. So just using 3/4 is fine. (Many dancers count waltzes as repeated 1,2,3 and some count as 1,2,3,4,5,6; like 4/4 is counted as either eighth notes or measure pairs.) Still modern conventions beat those from 1200-1500.